# how to dynamically enter the URL for WebSocket?

Tags: javascript, node.js, url, websocket, node-red

how to dynamically enter the URL for WebSocket in node-red?
[image]

[image]

Url websocket determined in f1 functions as a substitute it?

Comment: show your code here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically change the end point that the Websocket-out node connects to

Comment: What if you want to join in on the token? That is, for example: WSS: //example.com/token/device, where the token is changed?

Comment: Exactly, we need to have an option for dynamic value selection. Maybe on wss://${username}:${password}/example.com/ws or on wss://example.com/ws?acess_token=${access_token}.

Comment: As stated in the answer this is not currently possible with the design of the Websocket nodes

Comment: Is there any way to make things dynamic and hence we can pass that value through query params?

Comment: No, the connection is established at deploy time, not when the messages arrive

Comment: Sitting here in 2023 wondering why we still can't do that?  I'm using the HTTP Request node to call Slack API to get the *intial* URL that I need to feed into the websocket listener.  There HAS to be a way!

Comment: @WillBelden feel free to open a Pull Request against the project if you think you can come up with a way to make this work within the bounds of the WS node's design, and if not you are also free to implement a contrib node that works how you would like. But commenting on a 6 year old question "Why isn't this fixed yet" doesn't really help anybody.

Comment: You're right @hardlib but I did find a way to do it, just... not at all elegant.  Have to use regular "function" nodes instead of the special websocket based node.  Maybe what I have so far will help someone: https://gist.github.com/CaptainPalapa/88b601384eef38870a51836eef4f0cb4

Comment: Then write it up as a proper answer